# Интерфейсы C++ наподобие Java interface

Tags: java, c++, интерфейс

Изучал Java, сейчас захотелось чуть чуть подучить C++. Захотел изобрести такой велосипед, как сортировку. Хотел сделать на C++ некое подобие вот такой штуки.

```
Collections.sort( list, new Comparator< T >( ){...} );
```

Что я для этого сделал:
сам метод sort:

```
public:void sort(Comparable<Type> comparable){}
```

Абстрактный класс:

```
class Comparable{
            public:
            virtual ~Comparable(){
            }       
            virtual int compare(Type el1,Type el2)=0;
        };
```

и сам вызов метода sort из int main

```
class Compare :Comparable<int>{
                    public:
                        virtual int compare(int el1,int el2){
                            if(el1>el2){
                                return 1;
                            }else{
                                return -1;
                            }   
                        }
                };          
            lh.sort(Compare comp);
```

Где-то я допустил ошибку по своей неопытности)). Код не компилируется ))
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я тут не прав)).
З.Ы.
Попробую еще раз уточнить свой вопрос:
Мне необходимо сделать параметром функции - экземпляр класса, унаследованного от интерфейса

Comment: Ну как минимум `class Compare : public Comparable<int>`

Answer (score 0):

```
lh.sort(Compare())
```

Еще, наверное, int compare(...) должен вернуть ноль, если аргументы равны

Comment: Конкретно для решения моей задачи это не необходимо, у меня элементы меняются местами если только предыдущий больше текущего, т.е. результат работы функции = 1

Comment: Ок. Но лучше чтоб compare честно выдавал (-1, 0, 1) не задумываясь об алгоритме, а алгорим гарантировал что сохранит порядок сортировки равных элементов. Таким образом ты правильно разделяешь ответственнось кода.

Comment: Хорошо, я учту это, однако это не решает моей проблемы !)